Client Windows Service And Vb Asp net page
We have website page made in asp.net vb  that offer services for subscribers customer
WebPage is usb dongle secured by instruction and library of usb key manufacturer.
For various reason i must disallow users of our website to share webpage using teamviewer supremo or similar.
I thing installing a windows service on client machine to check if some remote connection is present( i know already how to create a function that answer true or false if remote connection is present)
Now the point: how can website asp page comunicate to client windows service asking: is remote connection active?
Thanks
I have not yet idea for comunication
